# Inkscape 1.2.2: How to resize existing Text objects and have that object be the last used style for newly added Text objects

Tags: inkscape, text, resize

Version info:

1. Inkscape: Inkscape 1.2.2 (732a01da63, 2022-12-09)
2. Operating system: Running on Microsoft Windows 10

---

Steps to reproduce what I *think* might be a defect, *or* I'm simply not doing it the way it should be done:

Add a Text object. Notice that it is way to large or way to small.

Select the Text object, and use the CTRL and arrow keys on the resize handles to resize the text proportionally until it is the correct size to use.

Open up Edit/Preferences, and click on **Tools/Shapes/Text**.

See **Style of new objects** is set to **Last used style**:

[image]

(leave that window up).

Click back into the Inkscape window, and add a *new* Text object.

See that the Text object is still way to large or way to small.

I had resized the previous text object, but Inkscape apparently is not considering that resized object to be the last object.

Now, the partially working workaround: In the preferences view, do this:

1. Click on **This tool's own style**
2. Click on the properly sized Text  object in side the Inkscape Window
3. Click on **Take from selection**

Visually:

[image]

Then add a new text object. See that it is resized to the selected Text object, as expected.

But here is the question: How do I *then* change some existing Text object by resizing it using the resize handles, and then be able to add new Text objects *that then use that newly resized Text object* as the size/style/whatever-it-is-called when creating the new Text object, **without** forcing me to use the above workaround above of reopening the Preferences dialog box, repeatedly?  I ask this because that workaround is a time-waster when adding different sized Text objects.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that setting the text-style to use for new objects can be a bit finicky. I've found that opening the 'Text → Text and Font...' panel and using the 'Set as default' button works a bit more consistently.

[image: 'Text and Font' panel inside Inkscape with 'Set as default' button highlighted.]

Also, setting the text size and other settings in the toolbar without any object selected or *before* typing any text when single-clicking on the canvas (as opposed to dragging a text-box) usually makes it stick for future objects as well.

Comment: I agree that might be a workaround for my question. However I don't want to do it that way. I want to be able to adjust the size with the size handles on the object inside the drawing area , without having to think about the details of fonts, and have the burden of figuring out that text size and font dialog box, which I find cumbersome and tedious. But, thank you for your observation.

Comment: @bgoodr Yes, I understood what you were talking about. Just adjust the text however you want on the canvas and hit the 'Set as default' button afterwards. Resizing with the arrows sets the 'Font size' input inside the panel. You only need to keep the panel docked on the right and occasionally click the button when you change the current text object. I don't think there is any other way to make Inkscape remember the font size.

Comment: got it. I will have to try that next time.